# Joomla Zoo Items not displaying after server move

Tags: php, joomla, joomla1.5

I've been tasked with upgrading a Joomla 1.5 site to a new and more secure version. Disclaimer: I hadn't ever used Joomla 3 days ago...
I have copied everything onto a localhost server i have setup (ubuntu) and have copied everything, incl the dbs, and most things seem to be working except for the Zoo Items. At least I'm pretty sure that's what the problem is. On the live site, the sub pages load up and there is a panel in the middle that shows a bunch of pictures rotating etc, and when I right click on it, it's a flash file.   On my version, the page loads, but the panel just stays blank (empty; same as bg color).

The items are all public and published and so are the categories they are in.  The items are in the database under jos_zoo_item and all have the access set to 0. I read that it is 1 in 2.5, so just for kicks I tried setting them all to 1 in the db and it broke my pages, so I know it's reading the db.

Under the Module manager I see the 4 items ZOO Item, Comment, Tag and Category, so I tried enabling them, even though I see they are not on on the live site, but taht juat adds boxes on the left that say those things...

A little help with where I'm going wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Zoo has had some pretty major changes since the last developed version for Joomla 1.5

You should download a fresh copy of Zoo which is specifically for Joomla 3.x and install it. the version you have now most likely has deprecated code. A thing to remember is that upgrading Joomla does **not** also upgrade you 3rd party extensions, such as Zoo. This has to be manually done.

Comment: I'm still using version 1.5 though. I'm just trying to get it up and running so I'll know if the upgrade worked at all.